# Is it possible to unprotect a copy protected PDF by recovering the character mapping using OCR?

Tags: pdf, unicode, ocr

There is a certain way of restricting the ability to copy text from a PDF which works by mapping each character of the used fonts to random characters of the so called *private* area of the Unicode specification. If the reader of such a protected PDF tries to copy a section of the text, all he or she gets is a string of glyphs like this:

```
!
```

My question is: Is there a way of correcting this map using perhaps an OCR algorithm to figure out what each character is supposed to be mapped to? The matter could perhaps be more difficult if the mapping is not injective, i.e. if it is additionally garbled in a way that the same character is mapped to different locations of the Unicode character space.

Comment: What is the scope? It sounds like another arms race much like the One Captcha has been going through. Figure out how to beat OCR, OCR gets better / learns that trick.

Comment: Probably not. First note that cryptography in computers generally occurs at the binary level, so encoded character schemes don't have as much pertinence to the output as you might expect. Second, static character mappings were not considered secure in 1910, let alone 2010, so it is very very unlikely that Adobe choose to implement one. And all this is assuming that the actual text copied is the real cyphertext for the phrase. Since modern PDFs use AES128 or stronger symetric key crypto, your best attack will be to locate the key.  if it is not present, you are sunk.

Comment: If the PDF is digitally generated (as opposed to scanned), OCR works very well. Try deleting the text layer (e.g. by printing it as a PDF again) and OCRing it?